# New Wifi Card Disconnects after 1 hour?

Tags: wireless, internet

Hello I just installed a new TL-WDN4800 wifi card in my Ubuntu 16.04 Pc.  The card works great except after about one hour the card quits working even though it still shows that it is connected to the internet in the top right corner.  After using the command sudo server network-manager restart the internet starts working again.  I hope this is enough information thank you for your time.

Relevant output from `lspci -knn`:

```
Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0030]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k Kernel modules: ath9k 03:00.0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `lspci -knn`

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0030] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:3112]
 Kernel driver in use: ath9k
 Kernel modules: ath9k
03:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Fresco Logic FL1100 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1b73:1100] (rev 10)
 Subsystem: Fresco Logic FL1100 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1b73:1100]
 Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
I was unable to post all the output here so I think I just got the parts about the wifi card